# Access the typescript react object

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I have this class:

```
  export class OpenEditRow {
  index: boolean;
  constructor(index: boolean) {
    this.index = index;
   }
 }
```

I have this class variable that has the values:

```
 0:true,
 1:false,
 2:false,
 3:true
```

How can I access the Boolean value found in key 3 of my object?

I have an variable:

```
 open : OpenEditRow;
```

How can I access the Boolean value found in key 3 of my object?

Comment: Did you try, `open[3]`?

Comment: Is your variable `open` is of class type ?